# How to assert list with fixtures list in Cypress

Tags: cypress, fixtures, assertion

I have Toolbar.json in fixtures directory. In that json file I have a list

```
{
"toolbar_elements": [

    "Contact",
    "Language",
    "About",
    "Privacy"
]
```

}

And I have a website with main menu which has these 4 elements.

```
<div class="mainMenu">
  <ul>
     <li>
       <a>Contact</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a>Language</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a>About</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a>Privacy</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

I want to make assertion and don't know how.

```
cy.get('[class="mainMenu"]').find('li').should('have.length', 4)
```

This passes. How can I check if list in Toolbar.json is the same as this in mainMenu?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.fixture('Toolbar.json').then((toolbar) => {
  cy.get('.mainMenu ul li a').each(($ele, index) => {
    expect(toolbar.toolbar_elements[index]).to.equal($ele.text().trim())
  })
})
```